# Android Widget not working

Tags: java, android, xml, widget

I have no idea what's going on. My OnReceive method is never called. It's probably something in the manifest.

Widget Provider:

```
package com.net_refresh;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;

public class NetRefreshWidget extends AppWidgetProvider
{
    private static final String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "ActionRecieverWidget";
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appwidgetmanager, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        final int length = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, NetRefreshWidget.class);
            intent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_initial_layout);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pendingIntent);

            appwidgetmanager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
    }

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context)
{

}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context)
{

}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER))
    {
        //Top secret code here.
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"
    package="com.net_refresh" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".NetRefresh">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".NetRefreshWidget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"     android:resource="@xml/widget_info"/>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Widget info XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:minWidth="72dp"
  android:minHeight="72dp"
  android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
  android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_initial_layout"
  >
</appwidget-provider>
```

Widget layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/widget_root"
  android:layout_width="72dp" 
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:layout_height="72dp"
  >
<Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
<ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"     android:src="@drawable/icon" android:clickable="true" android:adjustViewBounds="false"      android:id="@+id/img_refresh" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1">
</ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code says nothing without you to point the compiler's errors & warnings.

Anyway you can wrap your code into .apk and install it by yourself into your device, BUT this is the curve way, because everyone I know are using the eclipse and SDK tools.

Comment: There are no compiler errors / warnings. I just don't have my widget set up properly. I don't know what's wrong specifically though. It's probably something really simple that an intermediate user would be able to spot right away. Also, that wouldn't help with debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`. It may solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out a while back. I don't remember what I changed exactly but I at least added this line:

```
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER"/>
```

To the manifest, next to:

```
 <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
```

Very simple solution, now that I have an understanding of how broadcasts work.